# How to send 500*500 2D Int Array over Websocket?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, websocket

My Problem is that I think that it would take to long to JSON.stringify and send it to every individual User. Let's say 4 People would connect at the same time, the server would just be stuck at parsing the Array and everyone would have immense waiting time.

Is there a better way than JSON.stringify -ing ?

Comment: I think you underestimate how quick your server can parse JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Big-Friendly JSON. Asynchronous streaming functions for large JSON data sets:

> If you need to parse large JSON strings or stringify large JavaScript data sets, it makes sense to do so asynchronously rather than monopolising the event loop. BFJ implements those asynchronous functions.

See: https://github.com/philbooth/bfj